# PHP timestamp hours to days

Tags: php

I have a timestamp which I need to return as:

When it's under 1 hour I need it to say "30 minutes ago".
When it's under 24 hours I need it to say "6 hours ago".
When it gets to 24 hours I need it to say "1 day ago".
When it gets to 48 hours I need it to say "2 days ago".

Would this be done with a conditional statement?

So far I can return the number of days:

```html
$post_timestamp  = strtotime($post_timestamp);
$current_date = strtotime(time());
     
$datediff = $current_date - $post_timestamp;
$days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to look at [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for this use case.

Comment: Adding to Matt's comment, the method you're looking for is diffForHumans()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use `DateTime`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod`:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $post_timestamp); # I assume a unix timestamp here
//determine what interval should be used - 1 minute
$interval = new \DateInterval('PT1M');
//create periods every minute between the two dates
$periods = new \DatePeriod($date2, $interval, $date1);
//count the number of objects within the periods
$mins = iterator_count($periods);


if ($mins < 60)
{
    $say = "30 minutes ago";

} elseif ( $mins >= 60 and $mins < 60 * 24)
{
    $say = "6 hours ago";

} elseif ( $mins >= 60 * 24 and $mins < 60 * 48)
{
    $say = "1 day ago";

} elseif ( $mins >= 60 * 48)
{
    $say = "2 days ago";
}

print $say;
```

Comment: Works great thank you. From there I can work out the amount of hours and days from the amount of minutes to print

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like following :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
$post_timestamp="2017-05-21 5:00 pm";
$post_timestamp  = strtotime($post_timestamp);
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i a'));                 
$datediff = $current_date - $post_timestamp;
$mins = ($datediff) / 60;
$hours = $datediff / ( 60 * 60 );
```

You will get minutes and hours using this, put your condition accordingly